# MSTest V2: 'Test mix' section in Load test wizard not finding the unit test

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I'm trying to use my unit test for load testing as well. When I click 'Add...' button, visual studio prompts with a message 'There are no tests available to pick' (as shown in below image).

[image]

I can execute the unit test successfully from VS2017.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the solution structure I can't really tell.

Make sure the web test is present in same project as the load test.
Also make sure the project which you have created inside the solution is indeed a "Web Performance and Load Test Project".

Can you do the following :

1) Rebuild Solution

2) Clean / Build Solution

3) Renamed the coded Web Test

4) Restarted Visual Studio

5) Restarted Computer.